# Tagging in ios development

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, tags, tagging

I'm an absolute newbie on iOS Development at the minute so please pardon me if this seems like such a simple question to ask.

I want to build a project - almost like a note taking application - in which the user will be able to associate tags to their inputs. I'm sure many have seen them before - it's used in things like hashtags, or to give an example of an iOS app - Journalling apps like DayOne have it. It's basically used to generate tags for easy retrieval of a particular article.

My question is - how do you go about creating these kinds of tags? Particularly - how do you implement the tagging system that can generate custom tags for articles in the app?

Is it something that is built into Cocoa/SDK or do i have to look at something more complex like Core Data (NSPredicates) to learn how to create something like that?

OR is it something that has to be done programatically rather than a built in system in SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing built into Cocoa or Cocoa Touch either, so you will have to use Core Data. But before you'd do that I highly recommend to study up on basic iOS development and start with something simpler because Core Data is a bit advanced and can be a lot of pain as a newbie.

Comment: You're asking about auto-tagging / getting tags from users / saving tags against data / tag lookup?

Comment: @Wain Pretty much. Let's say i have a note - and want to tag it with the word "class" - and then the user inputs it into the note so it can be searched for later under that tag keyword

Comment: @Rickye I've done a bit of iOS development but not a lot, and yes it will take a while before going into Core Data, but i need it basically as a starting point for where i will end up by the end of this year. Thanks for your input

Comment: @shineon88 If you want to start with Core Data I'd recommend Stanford's iOS development course it has some pretty good examples and explains really well how this all works. But not just about Core Data, it can take you to a next level if you watch the whole course and do the examples. It may take a while and sometimes you can get stuck but it worth the effort.

Comment: Definitely will look that up. For me - a starting point will ALWAYS be Simon Allardice (Lynda.com) just cos he explains things in one of the best ways possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a super simple form (i.e. there are many ways you can build on this to make it scalable):

1. If each note is text, create an object with properties for the text and the tags
2. Make the tags property an array of strings
3. Store the notes in an array initially (archive to save to disk, or just practice with a non-saved version)
4. Make the user enter the tags (auto-tagging is an interesting topic...)
5. Consider using a `token field` (google for 3rd party implementations) for tag entry

Now, when a user starts a search for tagged content, iterate through each of the notes you have and run a predicate on the tag array. This could be done using `NSPredicate`, or you could ensure that all tags are saved in lower case and, to start with, require exact matching - so you could use '[tagArray containsObject:userEnteredTag];`

Then:

1. Look at real predicates
2. Look at Core Data (or SQLite if you love it)

Comment: No problem. As a rule you should up-vote answers that were useful and mark answers that solved your problem (rather than just commenting ;-)  )

Comment: p.s. you may want to start with a search like https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=automatic+tagging+of+documents

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Core Data or SQLite3. Personally I would use SQLite but it is down to preference. I have used both but if you have any SQL knowledge then I wouldn't use Core Data. Having created an app with CoreData and using a lot of NSPredicates I found that the app had a lot of bug that appeared over time.
I changed it to use SQLite and now it runs perfectly.

As you are new to iOS I would recommend you take a look at Ray Wenderlich's tutorials. I learnt a lot from there.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app

Comment: This doesn't actually describe anything about tagging or recommendations for tag management, it's just a comment on whether to use Core Data with no real explanation of why...

Comment: Thanks for your input. I want to use core data because it will be synced via iCloud. I've heard it's better in that aspect however as a newbie i could be completely wrong.

Comment: That's true Wain. It is putting my in the right direction, however - how do you generate tags like that for iOS programs?

Comment: You can use iCloud without Core Data. Auto-tagging isn't necessarily easy (and has nothing specifically to do with iOS), you would need to research that topic...

Comment: If you are wanting to use Core Data I used this tutorial which gave me a good start to both Core Data and to tagging. I therefore hope it is of some use to you. http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates
I do agree with @Wain though as you may want to do some further research into the topic of tagging

Comment: @Wain thanks - that's particularly what i needed. I couldn't really find it anywhere. It's very hard to find something about tagging - that we partly take for granted.

Comment: @user1836482 Thanks for that. Can any of you guys give me a ground on where to start. It seems like it's a very hard subject to try and gather information about?